# Show a post from selected categories wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show one post from several categories.  My code just shows the first category post :\ any advice?

```
<?php

        $args = array(
        'cat' => 1,15,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => '1',
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

            while ($query->the_post()):

                the_title();
                the_post_thumbnail(array(200, 200));



            ?>
<?php  endwhile;
            endif;?>
```

Comment: what's the problem you are facing right now?

Comment: i said to query return 1 post from category that have id 1 and 15 , but it show just category 1 post

Comment: what about `'posts_per_page' => '1',` . Check that you have some pagination there?

Comment: second category have just 1 post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `'posts_per_page' => '1'` so you are getting exactly what you ask: 1 post. Either from category 1 or 15, whichever is the most recent post.
If you want 1 post from EACH category, I would just loop your code, with a different category each time (just 1).

Only thing is, that will be in order of the category IDs you give and not sorted on date on something else. Also, if you have a post in multiple categories, you might end up with the same post twice.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the code to understand how to show post items from selected category items by passing the category ID.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'post', // post type
        'posts_per_page'    => -1, // number of post items
        'tax_query'         => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                'field'     => 'term_id',
                'terms'     => array( 16, 244 ) // pass the ID of the post category, separated by a comma.
            )
        )
    );
```